# Rewrite URL for taxonomy listing

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I have created several custom taxonomies and each "archive" can be viewed on the url mysite.com/taxonomy/term

Is it possible to rewrite the URLs so my taxonomy archive lives under for example mysite.com/calendar/taxonomy/term instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a custom post type you can define the slug using the argument "rewrite"
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
or you could use a plugin
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

Comment: There's actually a rewrite parameter which can be set for custom taxonomy as well: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Arguments